# Pause on hover News Slider/Ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know nothing of jquery/js but i applied a News Slider/Ticker script that I found online to my website home page.  The script itself works fine. The html and css parts were easy enough but I can't find the proper way to make it **PAUSE ON HOVER**. The .js file that came with it is lengthy and has much that I suspect isn't even being used, but as I said, I don't know js.  Sorry for the long js file but I don't know what parts are even involved. Can somebody help this complete novice?

```
(function ($) {
$.simpleTicker = function (elem, options) {
var defaults = {
  speed: 1000,
  delay: 4000,
  easing: 'swing',
  effectType: 'slide'
};

var param = {
  'ul': '',
  'li': '',
  'initList': '',
  'ulWidth': '',
  'liHeight': '',
  'tickerHook': 'tickerHook',
  'effect': {}
};

var plugin = this;
plugin.settings = {};

var $element = $(elem),
  element = elem;

plugin.init = function () {
  plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
  param.ul = element.children('ul');
  param.li = element.find('li');
  param.initList = element.find('li:first');
  param.ulWidth = param.ul.width();
  param.liHeight = param.li.height();

  element.css({
    height: (param.liHeight)
  });
  param.li.css({
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    position: 'absolute'
  });

  //dispatch
  switch (plugin.settings.effectType) {
    case 'fade':
      plugin.effect.fade();
      break;
    case 'roll':
      plugin.effect.roll();
      break;
    case 'slide':
      plugin.effect.slide();
      break;
  }
  plugin.effect.exec();
};

plugin.effect = {};

plugin.effect.exec = function () {
  param.initList.css(param.effect.init.css)
    .animate(param.effect.init.animate, plugin.settings.speed, plugin.settings.easing)
    .addClass(param.tickerHook);
  if (element.find(param.li).length > 1) {
    setInterval(function () {
      element.find('.' + param.tickerHook)
        .animate(param.effect.start.animate, plugin.settings.speed, plugin.settings.easing)
        .next()
        .css(param.effect.next.css)
        .animate(param.effect.next.animate, plugin.settings.speed, plugin.settings.easing)
        .addClass(param.tickerHook)
        .end()
        .appendTo(param.ul)
        .css(param.effect.end.css)
        .removeClass(param.tickerHook);
    }, plugin.settings.delay);
  }
};

plugin.effect.fade = function () {
  param.effect = {
    'init': {
      'css': {
        display: 'block',
        opacity: '0'
      },
      'animate': {
        opacity: '1',
        zIndex: '98'
      }
    },
    'start': {
      'animate': {
        opacity: '0'
      }
    },
    'next': {
      'css': {
        display: 'block',
        opacity: '0',
        zIndex: '99'
      },
      'animate': {
        opacity: '1'
      }
    },
    'end': {
      'css': {
        display: 'none',
        zIndex: '98'
      }
    }
  };
};

plugin.effect.roll = function () {
  param.effect = {
    'init': {
      'css': {
        top: '3em',
        display: 'block',
        opacity: '0'
      },
      'animate': {
        top: '0',
        opacity: '1',
        zIndex: '98'
      }
    },
    'start': {
      'animate': {
        top: '-3em',
        opacity: '0'
      }
    },
    'next': {
      'css': {
        top: '3em',
        display: 'block',
        opacity: '0',
        zIndex: '99'
      },
      'animate': {
        top: '0',
        opacity: '1'
      }
    },
    'end': {
      'css': {
        zIndex: '98'
      }
    }
  };
};


plugin.effect.slide = function () {
  param.effect = {
    'init': {
      'css': {
        left: (200),
        display: 'block',
        opacity: '0'
      },
      'animate': {
        left: '0',
        opacity: '1',
        zIndex: '98'
      }
    },
    'start': {
      'animate': {
        left: (-(200)),
        opacity: '0'
      }
    },
    'next': {
      'css': {
        left: (param.ulWidth),
        display: 'block',
        opacity: '0',
        zIndex: '99'
      },
      'animate': {
        left: '0',
        opacity: '1'
      }
    },
    'end': {
      'css': {
        zIndex: '98'
      }
    }
  };
};

plugin.init();
};

$.fn.simpleTicker = function (options) {
return this.each(function () {
  if (undefined == $(this).data('simpleTicker')) {
    var plugin = new $.simpleTiecker(this, options);
    $(this).data('simpleTicker', plugin);
  }
});
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Code that works in a fiddle would help us help you. Without being able to test anything, it seems as though you could also put a conditional in `if (element.find(param.li).length > 1 && *** 'elem is not being hovered' *** );` to check and fire the animation only if the element/container isn't being hovered on. If that makes sense.

Comment: Well, not only am I ignorant where js is concerned, I'm also new to jsfiddle.  I will try to work that out to help you help me.

Comment: OK, if you please, I need to pause on hover.  https://jsfiddle.net/jimp124/o7e1spck/13/

Comment: Can you link to the slider that you used? There may be an option to pause on hover built-in.

Comment: This is where I downloaded it from:  https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/HTML-List-Based-Scroller-Ticker-Plugin-jQuery-simpleTicker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, that library is old and very very complicated to work with. I would personally recommend you move to something along the lines of Slick Slider.

Slick: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

You can use the CDN version `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>`

I was able to recreate your use case in about 5min (with hover pause) with Click. Because it's an actual slider, it's better to wrap things in `<div>` containers, so I've done so in the fiddle I've shown you. You can tweak the CSS opacity animations to taste, but it's basically what you're doing now.

The Fiddle: [Slick Slider](https://jsfiddle.net/jrhager84/x4eds7o8/26/)

Comment: Joel, I appreciate your patience. I would never have known the library is old.  What you did is EXACLTY what I wanted.  I'm not getting it to work on my website so I must be implementing it wrong.  I'm not clear, am I supposed to be trashing the old js completely or adding your script (the portion in the javascript section on Fiddle) to it? What parts exactly need to go in the <head> on the page? I'm fully willing to change to something different as long as it looks and works the same.  Jim

Comment: You add the cdn script tags in your html in the head, and you can put the js from the fiddle in a script tag right below your closing body tag.

Comment: Also - I'd appreciate it if you marked the question answered, as it will help others with this issue as well. I'll help you get it configured also. :)

Comment: Forgot to mention: if you upvote the answer, it will be shown preference if somebody provides another answer. If you feel it best answered your question, I'd kindly ask for you to upvote it as well. Glad to be of help!

Comment: Looks like I'm too new to upvote, less that 15 reputation (I'm at 13)

Comment: I don't see slickSlider on there, or the code I gave at all. I just see the simpleTicker scrips and sources.

Is this a static HTML site?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I was unable to get the slickSlider to work so I did not upload it.  I only suggested you have a look in the event I didn't tell you something important.  Yes, it is an old static HTML site. Not my creation, I belong to the org and volunteered to help.

Comment: BTW, I deleted the comment with the site address.

Comment: Well, I'm more than willing to help you get the HTML fixed if you need. It's really simple to do, actually, as I only need to remove the scripts for the ticker and add the cdn for slick.

If you provide me with the HTML file you're using, I can easily fix it for ya. ;)

Comment: I appreciate it.  I think the problem on my end is other things in my css style sheet that may be interfering.  I'm going check that out today and I'll let you know the results. BTW, I use Dreamweaver CC for editing and when I try to look at your CDN version, I get  "Failed to fetch version info for slick-carousel%401.8.1."

Comment: How do I send you the html?

Comment: Joel, things were as I suspected and I was able to get the new slide on the home page live, it is running fine now.  I do appreciate all the help you've given me.  Along the way I also learned about stackoverflow and jsfiddle for which this was the first time I used either of them.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted! :)

Comment: I'm curious about something.  Currently I have 4 sliding items.  It always starts with them in the order listed.  After all 4 are complete, the first one doesn't slide in but just appears. Is there a way to make it loop continuously?

Comment: There are some hacks to do it. It uses clones to simulate wrap, so you have to target the clone and add special stuff via css. It's a common issue with sliders.

Comment: Try adding this to css:......`.slick-slider div { transition: none; }`